# Asking Windows for real-time priority

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This code snippet is about asking Windows for the highest possible execution priority. Basically, we have to ask for real-time **priority class** for the entire process, after which each thread has to ask for real-time **thread priorities**. However, since Windows Vista, whatever is the program that needs the real-time priority, it **must** be asked to be run in administrator privilege level.

The demonstration program I provide simply loops for 7 seconds. During that period, your system should be frozen (try pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>; should not switch the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> light). Also, if you put on some audio, the sound card will repeat its contents of the sound buffer over and over again.

**rtprio.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL RealTimePriorityClass()
{
    return SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
}

BOOL RealTimeThreadPriority()
{
    return SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "rtprio.h"

static const DWORD dwInterval = 7000; // millseconds.

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParams);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,
    HINSTANCE hPrev,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nShowCmd)
{
    DWORD       i;
    DWORD       dwInitTicks;
    DWORD       dwCores;
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;

    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
    dwCores = sysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;

    // Ask real-time priority class for the entire process.
    RealTimePriorityClass();

    for (i = 0; i < dwCores - 1; i++)
    {
        CreateThread(NULL,
                     0,
                     ThreadProc,
                     NULL,
                     0,
                     NULL);
    }

    RealTimeThreadPriority();

    dwInitTicks = GetTickCount();

    while (GetTickCount() - dwInitTicks < dwInterval);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParams)
{
    // Ask for real-time priority for this thread.
    RealTimeThreadPriority();

    // Freeze the system for dwInterval milliseconds.
    while (TRUE) {}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is wise to ask us to test code that will lock up your PC for 7 seconds... :p

Comment: You scared? ;-)

Comment: @DanPantry Since there is a warning label attached, I'm all for it.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is?

Comment: Tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

Works as intended.
But I get a thread priority of 15 rather than the expected 31 for a `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`?
See [SetThreadPriority](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority).

It seems that the `THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL` is defined to `THREAD_BASE_PRIORITY_LOWRT - 1`, which could be further elevated to 31 if needed.